# What exercise is this (rotating upper body holding a 20kg plate)?

Tags: weightlifting

One of the players in my favourite sporting team the (Go the All Blacks!) does this interesting rotating exercise. My question; I'm wondering what the exercise is called, what benefits would you gain from the exercise/ the muscles it affects and how to preform the right technique. From the clip it almost looks like some kind of strengthening for the core.

Please view [Rotating and lifting heavy plates](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SaiJeKArIj8&feature=share#start=1:50;) the exercise is at index 1.50 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Around the head plate drill......I've heard it call the plate crown also.  Here's a link to the Men's Health version of it: http://www.menshealth.com/workout-center/e/around-the-head-plate-drill/27532
[image]